# Limitless amount of posts in custom archive page

Tags: loop, customization, pagination, query-posts, archive-template

I want to get rid of pagination completely on my custom archive, I want everything on 1 page. How can I do this?

Currently I'm getting my posts with:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

The codex pages on [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts?codekitCB=408739025.043388) and [pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query) don't seem much help, they're just telling me how to limit it but not saying how I can get rid of the limit.

I've used the [bones](http://themble.com/bones/) starter theme so I don't know if that affects the default behaviour.

Comment: `query_posts()` should not be used, what you actually need to use for this is `pre_get_posts` hook. Please search around site for info on it (now that you know what to look for), there is plenty. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `query_posts()`.
Try:

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query('orderby=title&order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1');
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Comment: Why do you think this will solve the problem? Why shouldn't we use `query_posts()` and use custom `WP_Query` instead? (I'm not arguing that using `query_posts` is a bad idea in this case, but using custom `WP_Query` doesn't make any difference in this case, I guess).

Comment: Now - no difference. But WP_Query is more flexible and cuztomizable. This is archive page, it is important. In the future he plobable will need to combine queries, use GET queries or etc. what query_posts can't provide. So, that's why it is more convenient to write WP_Query now, instead of replace query_posts in future.

http://www.rarst.net/images/query_functions.png

Comment: Well... 1. You can use exactly the same params with `query_posts` as in `WP_Query`, so I don't get why is the latter more flexible. 2. Since it's archive (and performance is important), you should use `pre_get_posts` filter and not `query_posts`/`WP_Query`.